# Input validation in MVC

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I need a little help regarding design of MVC .
Most of the tutorials of MVC and CODEIGNITER are doing input validation in controller. Is it a good practice ?
Suppose we implement REST or SOAP API then we are going to have different controllers, and for all those controllers I need to replicate my code. Later if any of the validation rule is changed, it will get rippled into all controllers. Shouldn't all the validation should be inside Model instead of Controller ? 
One more thing I would like to ask. As I am trying to keep my functions as cohesive as possible, I am getting one to one relation between functions of model and controller. Is it ok or I am doing things wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding doing input validation in Controller
   Ans. Yes, that is the generally accepted practice in most MVCs. However, during the past few years, due to the advent of AJAX frameworks and more adoption of JavaScript, many UI validations get done in UI itself(called client-side validations). These are generally displayed as javascript alert boxes and do not allow user to go ahead unless he fixes these errors. So, I would say Controllers/View helpers are de-facto places where validations are done but you should consider client-side validations wherever feasible. It also saves you trips to the server.
2. If you expose the same as functionality as SOAP/REST
   Ans. Now-a-days you can annotate the same controller methods to make them work as web service endpoints. So, your controllers can service both web-based requests and also SOAP/REST requests.
   But one note of caution - your form-beans/backing beans should be very well designed. I have seen code where hibernate model objects are used as form-backing objects. This makes it tricky when you generate a WSDL out of the form-backing objects as hibernate model objects may have many linked entities and one ends up with very complex xml structures in the request/response.
   But still, if you design your backing-beans as fine-grained, i.e. not having complex objects, then you should be comfortably placed in using your existing controller/controller methods as web service endpoints for both SOAP/REST.
3. Regarding the validations being inside Model layer
   Ans. You can use this thumb rule to determine where to place which validations -

   - Business validations should happen in models/services
   - complex client validations, which are not feasible in client-side, should happen in controllers/view helpers
   - UI validations (formatting/empty checks) should happen via client-side/javascript validations
4. Regarding one to one relation between functions of controller and model/service
   Ans. Its fine. Just remember to have one controller method talk to its respective model method. And if multiple models are needed to service a request, then that model method should act as an aggregator of information from multiple models i.e. the controller should contact its main model and the main model should contact other models.

Comment: I got your point but I have few confusions. Can we rely on client side validation ? A client can always by-pass validation by disabling javascript or by playing with http request headers. If a model calls another model then isn't SOC is violated as a the cohesion of model get reduced ? Can u provide me some link or example that describes the pitfalls of making a controller talk to multiple models. Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: Yes, you can rely on client side validations. Basically you only submit your form when all the client side validations passes. If you look at all major websites they rely heavily on javascript. And only a few have non-javascript versions. Regarding model calling model, its a generally accepted practice to have service call service for business logic. I do not mean DAO calling DAO. DAOs should exclusively be called from their respective services. Lastly, I have worked in many web-based projects and my answers are based on that. I do not have an at-hand list of reference websites.

Comment: @KrrishRaj Client side validation can be relied on but may not, and probably should not, totally eliminate the need for back-end validation. Model calling model would, IMO, clearly violate SOC. On the other hand, having a Controller utilize multiple models would seem to me to be how you create SOC. CodeIgniter will allow you to load models inside another model. The pitfall you could most easily fall into this way is a dependency issue. In particular, circular references are all to easily constructed.

Comment: @KrrishRaj I saw your mail... facing some problem with mailing to hotmail from javabrahman. Can you please send me a mail from a non-hotmail id, I will reply to your mail by this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a good practice? In my experience yes.

One thing to keep in mind is that any given controller can display an number of different pages. For example, consider a "Dashboard" which could have multiple tasks each of which requires its own page.

A rough pseudo-codeish "Dashboard" controller might look like this:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('somemodel_model');
  }
  public function index(){
   //displays a task selection page with links to various tasks
  }  
  public function admins(){
    //some kind of interface to display and edit admin level users
  }
  public function users(){
    //CRUD for dashboard users
  }
}
```

With this controller the task selection page is opened with `baseurl/dashboard`, adminstrator's page with `baseurl/dashboard/admins` and user CRUD with `baseurl/dashboard/users`. Because each of these share the same Class, code needed by all/many of these pages (like validation) can be implemented in the constructor and/or with private methods. You probably already know all this. Keep in mind that AJAX responders can also reside in a controller using the same technique.

In regards to keeping the validation rules DRY and easing the work required for changes to rules CI can store sets of rules in a config file for easy reuse in multiple situations. [Read about it.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#saving-sets-of-validation-rules-to-a-config-file)